# Dynamically select the Conditional Formatting range based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

looking for a conditional formatting trick to do this.

if value of Cell A1 = 1 then cell B1 should be Formatted. If the value of A1 = 2 then Cell B2.

conditional Formatting range should be changed dynamically based on value of cell A1.

Comment: Can you show the code you've started.  You are not asking the right question either, you need to `get value from range` and then use that value to `set range` all will be google-able or available via help.  Select Range Based on Cell Value is what you are really after.  so `dynamicrange.formatconditions.add`

Comment: this is just an example.  Think of a situation below..

I have 2 cells dedicated to enter two values. when I click/Select that cell, only that cells Text & Borders borders should get formatted. if I select the Other only That cells Text & Borders should be formatted.. 

I would like a Pure Excel solution if possible. Else, VBA would do..

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved with *Conditional Formatting*, no need for VBA.

Mark your cells B1+B2, Choose *Conditional Formatting* (from Home-Tab), New Rule, Select "Use a formula...", enter `=$A$1=ROW()` as formula and set the Format to whatever you want.

**UPDATE** (after your comment what you want to format)
If the ranges you wan to format are always the same size and with the same distance, you can use a formula like

```
=AND(MOD(COLUMN()-1,4)>0,INT((COLUMN()-1)/4)+1=$A$1,ROW()>=5,ROW()<=10)
```

This checks if the row is between 5 and 10 and divide the column by 4 to check in which "block" you are. The `Mod`-part prevents the formatting of col `A`, `E`...

If the blocks you want to format are more complicated, you could solve this with an UDF:

```
Public Function calcFormattingVal(r As Range) As Integer
    If Not Intersect(Range("B5:D10"), r) Is Nothing Then
        calcFormattingVal = 1
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Range("F5:H10"), r) Is Nothing Then
        calcFormattingVal = 2
    Else
        calcFormattingVal = -999
    End If
End Function
```

Now, put the following formula as conditional formatting. Be aware that you have to pass the address of upper left cell where your formatting starts as parameter to the function. So if you mark the range `"B5:H12"`, use `B5` as parameter.

```
=calcformattingval(B5)=$A$1
```

Comment: this is not my actual code. this is just an example. think about two ranges containing 100 cells in each range..

Comment: Which of the cells in range1 should react on which cell in range2?

Comment: if A1 = 1 Then Range("B5"D10"). if A1 = 2  Range("F5"H10").
I know i can use two conditional formatting rules. But, I'm looking for One Conditional Formatting Rule. So the Range should be Selected Dynamically..

Comment: @Rapto: Updated my answer, have a look